# How to remove clicked div and corresponding item in menu

Tags: jquery, css

i wanted removeclass is click this parent is remove and iconclass is remove please helpme......

```
<div class="itemlabel">
<div class="icon"><a href="#select1">1</a></div>
<div class="icon"><a href="#select2">2</a></div>
<div class="icon"><a href="#select3">3</a></div>
<div class="icon"><a href="#select4">4</a></div>
<div class="icon"><a href="#select5">5</a></div>
<div class="icon"><a href="#select6">6</a></div>
<div class="icon"><a href="#select7">7</a></div>
<div class="icon"><a href="#select8">8</a></div>
<div style="clear:both"></div>
</div>
```

//css

```
 .remove{
   display:inline-block;
   padding:20px;
   background-color:red;
    color:#fff;
    margin:10px;
   cursor:pointer;
}
```

// jquery

```
$(".remove").on('click', function() {
    $(this).parent().remove();
    $(".itemlabel .icon").remove(); /*this is problem .. i want one icon remove but all  is remove */
});
```

see example how use thesame number remove iconclass

http://jsfiddle.net/kisspa/74xSc/

Comment: click 'useful' if you didn't understand the question :)

Comment: you answer is right.. thank

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will remove clicked div and corresponding itemlabel div

Try this

```
$(".remove").on('click', function() {
    $(this).parent().remove();
    var idd=$(this).next().attr('id')
    $('.itemlabel div').find('a[href="#'+idd+'"]').parent().remove();
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/74xSc/2/)

Answer (score 2):

Add a wrapper class and do this:

```
$(".item .remove").on('click', function() {
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    $(this).parent().parent().find('[href=#'+id+']').remove();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/74xSc/3/

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.remove').on('click', function() {
    // find enclosing item and determine position in parent container
    var $item = $(this).closest('.item'),
    indexToRemove = $item.index();

    // find corresponding item label and remove it together with item
    $('.itemlabel > .icon')
        .eq(indexToRemove)
        .add($item)
        .remove();
});
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/74xSc/5/)

Answer (score 1):

you mean like this: http://jsfiddle.net/74xSc/4/

```
var place=1;
$(".remove").on('click', function() {
    var value=$(this).siblings('.lablecircle').attr('id');
    var eq=parseInt(value.replace(/\D/g,''));
    $(this).parent().remove();
    $('.icon').eq(eq-place).remove();
    place++;
});
```